# Scrape data from a table with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrape data from a table with scrapy. The table html is like:

```
<table class="tablehd">

<tr class="colhead">
<td width="170">MON, NOV 11</td>
<td width="80">Item</td>
<td width="60" align="center"></td>
<td width="210">Item</td>
<td width="220">Item</td>
</tr>

<tr class="oddrow">
<td> Item </a></td>
<td> Item </td>
<td align="center"> Item </td>
<td></td>
<td> Item </td>
</tr>

<tr class="evenrow">
<td> Item </a></td>
<td> Item </td>
<td align="center"> Item </td>
<td></td>
<td> Item </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Entire list is avialable by

```
items = hxs.select('//table[@class="tablehd"]//td//text()').extract()
```

How would you split them to each item and then assign data td1 - td5ta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what exactly do you want to see in your items, but here's an example and I hope this is it:

```
class MyItem(Item):
    value = Field()


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = hxs.select('//table[@class="tablehd"]/td')

        for item in items:
            my_item = MyItem()
            my_item['value'] = item.select('.//text()').extract()
            yield my_item
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how would you approach multiple rows and colums

Comment: That depends. Please, show what do you want to see in the output (items) first.

Comment: it does work.. thanks.. trying to extract each item now.. have a row

Comment: Yup, thanks. Feel free to edit your question or ask different one, if you have problems with extracting items.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "split them to each item" do you mean each class/row?

Anyway, the way I would do it is simply to use a regular expression.

```
import urllib, re
html=urllib.urlopen('domain.com')
itemfinder=re.compile('td>(.*)</td>')
items=re.findall(itemfinder, html)
```

If you want to split it up by row, then:

```
rowfinder=('tr', re.Multiline)
rows=re.findall(rowfinder, html)
for row in rows:
    ...code above except substitute variables apropos
```

Comment: He is asking how to do it using Scrapy. Plus, basically, parsing html using regex is not a good idea.

Comment: Fair enough, wasn't sure, I thought I would offer a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Wouldn't we want to use a tool like BeautifulSoup in this case?